# AWS quicksight can't ingest csv from s3 but the same data uploaded as file works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

I am new to quicksight and was just test driving (on the quicksight web console. I'm not using the command line in this entire thing) with some data (can't share, confidential business info). I have a strange issue. when I create a dataset by uploading the file, which is only 50 mb, it works fine and I can see a preview of the table and I am able to proceed to the visualization. But when I upload the same file to the s3 and make a manifest and submit it using the 'use s3' option in the creat dataset window, I get the INCORRECT_FIELD_COUNT error.

here's the manifest file:

```
{
"fileLocations": [
    {
        "URIs": [
            "s3://testbucket/analytics/mydata.csv"
        ]
    },
    {
        "URIPrefixes": [
            "s3://testbucket/analytics/"
        ]
    }
],
"globalUploadSettings": {
    "format": "CSV",
    "delimiter": ",",
    "containsHeader": "true"
   }
}
```

I know the data is not fully structured with some rows where a few columns are missing but how is it possible for quicksight to automatically infer and put NULLs into shorter rows when uploaded from local machine but not as an s3 file with the manifest? are there some different setttings that i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same thing - looks like this is fairly new code. It'd be useful to know what the expected field count is, especially as it doesn't say if it's too few or too many (both are wrong). One of those technologies that looks promising, but I'd say there's a little maturing required.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer as you are asking for more information.
Please convert it to a comment, and when you have all the information needed, then write a more clear answer.